# Dropdown is not getting selected

Tags: asp.net

When I pass the string value to the dropdown, it is not getting selected. I am not sure why?

I've tried passing the value eg:`ddlInitialIncidentType.Items.FindByValue("1").Selected = true;` directly which works fine.

```
protected void btnIncTypeSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 string value;

 if (rbIncTypeY.Checked == true) {
  //getting the value number from the Label
  value = label.Text;
  ddlInitialIncidentType.ClearSelection();

  //here I want to select the dropdown with the value number
  ddlInitialIncidentType.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;

 }
}
```

Note: I am assigning the value to the label in the below method

```
 function prioritySelection(sender) {
                var e = document.getElementById(sender.id);
                e = e.value;

                if (e == 2 || e == 4 || e == 1 || e == 3) 
{
                    $('#<%=lblInitialIncidentTypeCurrent.ClientID%>').html(e);                                                $find("ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_ModalPopupIncidentTypeChange").show();
                    }
```

Comment: It is not easy to guess when this code is running. Try to add more code in your question by editing your question so that we may know the flow of the code.

Comment: Hi Gagan Deep,I've updated the code.

Comment: have you checked if you are getting the value in your label on button click.

Answer (score 0):

protected void btnIncTypeSave_Click(object sender,EventArgs e) 
{        string value;        if (rbIncTypeY.Checked==true)         {
  value=label.Text; // did you check here that value gets value or not?}        }

Comment: The value is present in the label, I've checked that but I am not sure whether this is the procedure to store the value of the label to the string

Comment: Do you fill your combobox with label.text value? i think ddlInitialIncidentType.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected can't find "value" so it return false.

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code you have used the ID of the Label control as `lblInitialIncidentTypeCurrent` where as in your server side code your are using some other Label control.

Replace this

```
value = label.Text;
```

with

```
value = lblInitialIncidentTypeCurrent.Text;
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake while copying it here.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem by using the Label to store the value.
But by using HiddenField it is solved.
Thanks all for the answers provided. 
below is the code for it,

```
    //aspx.cs

        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdtest" runat="server" />

         protected void btnIncTypeSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    string value;

                    if (rbIncTypeY.Checked ==true)
                    {
                        value = hdnIncType.Value;

                            ddlInitialIncidentType.ClearSelection();
                            ddlInitialIncidentType.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;


                        ModalPopupIncidentTypeChange.Hide();
                        rbIncTypeY.Checked = false;

                    }
}

        //aspx
                function prioritySelection(sender) {

                    var e = document.getElementById(sender.id);
                    e = e.value;
                    if (e == 2 || e == 4 || e == 1 || e == 3) {

                        $('#<%=hdtest.ClientID%>').val(e);                               
                        $find("ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_ModalPopupIncidentTypeChange").show();
                        }

                    }
```